# Sort dictionary with attribute value

Tags: python, sorting

I have a <s>list</s> dictionary like this: `{1: {'a': 5, 'score': 3}, 2: {'a': 6, 'score': 1}, 3: {'a': 7, 'score': 2}}` and want to sort it using its `score` attribute.
Intended output: `{2: {'a': 6, 'score': 1}, 3: {'a': 7, 'score': 2}, 1: {'a': 5, 'score': 3}}`

I have trying to use the built-in function to sort the list but its not giving desired output
`updatedList = sorted(b, key=lambda k: k['score'])`

Any hints how I can get the desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data structure is a nested dictionary, not a list.

To sort the dictionary, you can modify your `key` function to this:

```py
>>> d = {1: {'a': 5, 'score': 3}, 2: {'a': 6, 'score': 1}, 3: {'a': 7, 'score': 2}}
>>> dict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]['score']))
{2: {'a': 6, 'score': 1}, 3: {'a': 7, 'score': 2}, 1: {'a': 5, 'score': 3}}
```

Which converts the original dictionary to [`dict.items`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items), then uses the `score` key from the dictionary in the `(key, value)` tuple. Then after sorting with [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted), we can convert back to a dictionary with [`dict()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-dict).

This works in **Python 3.6+** since dictionaries are ordered. If you are using a lower python version, you can maintain dictionary insertion order with [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) instead.

Answer (score -1):

For sorting a **Nested Dictionary** use the `key` argument for `sorted()`. It lets you specify a function that, given the actual item being sorted, returns a value that should be sorted by.

```
N_Dictionary = {1: {'a': 5, 'score': 3}, 2: {'a': 6, 'score': 1}, 3: {'a': 7, 'score': 2}}
s_values = sorted(N_Dictionary.items(), key = lambda x: x[1]["score"] )
s_values
```